# Create a rts from a java component

Tags: java, swing, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to show what I display in a `JPanel` (or other swing container) also as a video using rtsp.

I have a video from a drone to my computer and I want to redirect the video to a surveillance server. The server can only add ipcamera and the drone can't work as ipcamera.

My idea was to take the video from the drone and add my computer as a "fake" ip camera to stream drone's video.
Can someone help me with some hints?